# IDRAC Virtual CD - where / how much space?

Tags: drac

Does IDRac use it's own amount of storage space? I'm trying to send Windows OS to its Virtual Media for an OS reinstall... it's about 5GB... where will it be stored on, on my dedicated server directly?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The virtual media is not stored anywhere on the server. It's loaded over the network on demand. This means less overall data will be transferred, as the installation is unlikely to need the entire 5GB of data, but it also means that the installation may be slow if your network connection is slow or you have a lot of latency between you (where you are running the Java client) and the server.

Comment: Thanks. After 2 hours of waiting for the OS Image to be mapped by IDRAC (not done yet!!) I'm starting to think that installation will also take forever... When you say loaded over the network does it mean that IDRAC uses RAM or something? I mean where is it kept in memory? Thanks again!

Comment: Whether any copy of it is kept in memory depends on the OS. You're just going to have to keep waiting, or get a faster (or shorter) network connection.

Comment: I'm thinking about sending the OS to my dedicated desktop and forget the clean install from idrac (i'm trying to upgrade from Windows_server_2008 to server_2016)... would that make more sense!?

Comment: The more common ways of OS install via an iso are virtual media in a remote administration, or physical disks in a DVD drive.  If you have a management desktop on the same local network as the server, you may have better performance loading the console and virtual media from there.